# Auth problem - Flutter Amplify won't let me access AWS Aurora MYSQL

Tags: amazon-web-services, flutter, dart, aws-amplify, aws-aurora-serverless

I'm trying to access AWS Aurora MYSQL from my Flutter App using the Amplify CLI in Android Studio according to these instructions;

https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/relational

Here are the steps I've taken;

```
amplify init
amplify add api
amplify api add-graphql-datasource
```

After choosing "mycluster" as the "Aurora Serverless cluster that will be used as the data source for your API: "

I get this error;

```
"No RDS access credentials found in the AWS Secrect Manager.my "mycluster" Aurora Mysql database"
```

This happens no matter what default authorization type for the API I choose (IAM, API key, Cognito user pool, etc.)

Is this a bug? How should I Proceed?

Comment: Did you find how to solve this? I'm getting the same error while try adds Aurora Postgres Serverless. Using AppSync Console is possible to add the cluster with no issue, only when using Amplify CLI does this error appear.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've decided I don't want to be tied into Amazons proprietary software so I  stopped using amplify.

Comment: After some hours digging the amplify codebase and issues on github, I could find that amplify does not support aurora postgres, only mysql at this time. This error, in particular, is raised cause amplify try to find a secret that is made by a prefix "rds-db-credentials/" + ClusterResourceId, but others issues came after solve this, so I moved to MySQL. https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/3081